# Color sequence Arduino in multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, arduino

I'm trying to store a sequence of RGB values in a multidimensional array:

```
void loop()
{  
  short colors[][3] = {{2,2,2},{4,4,4},{4,4,4}};
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    Serial.write("Debug 1");
    Serial.write("\n");
    setColor(colors[i][0],colors[i][1],colors[i][2]);
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

But If my array goes above a certain size, the Arduino UNO does random things and doesn't react anymore (doesn't print Debug 1 anymore, but instead some random characters).

Has anybody experience in doing that stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run out of RAM on the AVR microcontroller. Either use less RAM, by either reducing the scope of your project or finding a way to encode your data more densely, or use a AVR microcontroller that has more RAM in the first place such as the ATmega1284P.

Comment: Thank you! Then I'll see what I can do about the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is statically assigned to 3 elements, but you are reading 10!

Normally, C programs don't check array bounds - there's no such information on array sizes! So, when your accessing items `colors[>2][*]`, you are really reading memory after assigned array, which may be unassigned or assigned for something else, making your code vulnerable to data corruption or cause access violation exceptions. [Buffer overflow exploit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow#Exploitation) also explores unsafe code this way (very unlikely in Arduino, I think).

Comment: Sorry, my example code is a bit wrong. I used a larger array, but it doesn't make sense to post a 20 lines long multidimensional array on stackoverflow. The actual array was 10 long.